# Can't loop threw category from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

There are two tables in my database . **TABLE 1** contains category where **TABLE 2** contains category and its description .

for example

**TABLE 1**

id  ---   category
1   ---     abc

2   ---     eef

3   ---     lmn

**TABLE 2**

id --- category --- description

1  ---   abc    ---  gjhgjhdc

What I am really trying to achieve is to get 10 rows of data from each category of TABLE 1 . For example if i have 20 categories in TABLE 1, I need to fetch 10 rows from each of 20 categories from TABLE 2. I used below code and its only returns single category data, say like only from abc.

```
     <?php
public

function getAllUserTasks($last_limt, $nxt_limt)
{

    // include db connect class

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $response["messages"] = array();

    // get all category from category table

    $catagory = mysql_query("SELECT cat_type FROM category") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($catagory))
    {

        // temp user array

        $cat = array();
        $cat = $row["cat_type"];

        // get 10 messages from each category from message table

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sub_category = '$cat' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());

        // check for empty result

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {

            // looping through all results
            // products node

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                // temp user array

                $msgs = array();
                $msgs["id"] = $row["pid"];
                $msgs["language"] = $row["language"];
                $msgs["category"] = $row["category"];
                $msgs["sub_category"] = $row["sub_category"];
                $msgs["description"] = $row["description"];
                $msgs["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
                $msgs["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

                // push single product into final response array

                array_push($response["messages"], $msgs);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            // no products found

            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // success

    return $response;
      }
```

Comment: Why do you save the description in a separate table. And if you do, why do you save the category name in that table too?

Comment: Remove the die after your query

Comment: Why because category may be limited to 100 but anyone can add any amount of description to each category . Each same category may contains 1000 of different description .

Comment: @ aldrin27  did not worked

Answer (score 0):

You've used the same variable - $row - for the two mysql_fetch_array calls.

Change the second one, for example, to "$messageRow = mysql_fetch_array($result)" (and then use it inside its while) and it should fix it.